# Realize progress bar function

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
    Sub demo()
    Dim oPara As Paragraph
    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
           If oPara.style = "Body text" Then
               With oPara.Format
                    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
                    .SpaceAfter = Word.Application.LinesToPoints(0)
                    .SpaceBefore = Word.Application.LinesToPoints(0)
               End With
        End If
    Next oPara
End Sub
```

The vba code is  set every paragraphs with “ Body Text” style to some format，but I want to add
progress bar ,when the code run ,progress bar shows: current pages /total pages?

Comment: You might want to use [Progress Bar for Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/progress-bar-for-excel).

Comment: See https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Userforms/CreateAProgressBar.htm which uses a userform to give the Progress Bar.

Comment: You can avoid looping through the paragraphs simply by modifying the body text style, or by using find and replace to apply another style that has the settings you want, e.g. "No Spacing"

Answer (score 0):

As Timothy says:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleBodyText).ParagraphFormat
  .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
  .SpaceAfter = 0
  .SpaceBefore = 0
End With
End Sub
```

No looping required and, hence, no need for a progress bar.

Comment: thank you. but your  code only modify  a body test style . Maybe you are not clear my means : modfiy every  paragraph with bodytext style ,not include in heading style. some long document ,maybe contains thousands of paragraph,so，to add the progress bar is necessary ,fuction StatusBar is enough

Comment: Unless you have overridden the paragraph formatting attached to the "Body Text" Style, the code I posted modifies *every* paragraph using the "Body Text" Style (regardless of where it is used), which is what you asked for. It does this in one simple step and *does not* modify Heading Styles or other Styles. If you have other Styles you want to modify, use the same approach with them.